# Application name vs Main Activity name

Tags: android, android-activity

My Manifest is this:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity android:name=".MyFirstScreen" android:label="@string/first_screen_title" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    ....
 </application>
```

And my strings.xml is this:

```
 <string name="app_name">Test</string>
 <string name="first_screen_title">First Screen</string>
```

How can it be that when I run the app in my phone, the application's name is "First Screen" and not "Test"?? Simple solution would be to set the label of the first activity as the name of the application, but then it shows the name of the app in the ActionBar of the first activity. Yet another solution is to set by code the title of the ActionBar... Yes, I know there are multiple solutions, but I'm just looking for an explanation why I can't do it as I'm doing!

Answer (score 1):

That is normal you defined a separate lable for your launchrr activity while the app name is used for the list of installed apps etc.